# can't seem to generate a valid netplan YAML enough to connect to wifi

Tags: netplan

How do I know what the proper syntax for netplan is? I've looked up the netplan docs online and everything I try gives me KEY errors when I try to use netplan generate.

Comment: Have you checked here? `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml` The spacing, identation, quotes, etc. must be exact.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Desktop or server installation? If Desktop, you should be using NetworkManager, not netplan. See https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: status please...

Comment: @chili555 Sorry, to keep you guys waiting.. I was not aware that spacing and indentations were important.  Why it is that way is baffling to me...

It's feels like a step back instead of progress to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Ubuntu **Desktop** installation, you should be using NetworkManager, not netplan, to manage wireless connections.

Your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

then:

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate script files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

In a Ubuntu **Server** installation, you should be using netplan, and examples of netplan scripts can be seen [here](https://netplan.io/examples).

Minimal example...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlxxxxxx: # change this to the correct wireless interface name
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

then:

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate script files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you have key-errors then probably your netplan software is too old. Ubuntu LTS 18.04 has an old version. So you should upgrade your netplan.io package to make this work.

The ubuntu repository on http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/ contains a version like netplan.io_0.96-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb, or whatever architecture you might have.

I installed this on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS with:

dpkg -i netplan.io_0.96-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb

and it installs without further dependencies, so it is a drop-in replacement.